# Availability Group log_reuse_wait = Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transaction-log, availability-groups

We have a SQL 2014 Availability Group with 3 replicas of our primary database - 2 in our main data center and 1 in our DR center.

We did a large index rebuild on the primary which obviously needs to replicate to the secondaries. I believe this replication has now finished. When I run:

```
select redo_queue_size, log_send_queue_size 
from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states 
where database_id = 28
```

I get:

```
redo_queue_size |log_send_queue_size
0           | 0
0           | 0
NULL        | NULL
```

Which suggests to me that the replication has finished. However, when I run

```
select log_reuse_wait, log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.databases where database_id = 28
```

I get:

```
log_reuse_wait  | log_reuse_wait_desc
6               | REPLICATION
```

I found this query:

```
select * 
from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states 
where database_name = DB_NAME()
```

which shows the state of the replication which again suggests that everything is replicated, but it can't be truncated for some reason:

```
is_failover_ready   | is_pending_secondary_suspend  | recovery_lsn              | truncation_lsn
1                   | 0                             | 4294967295429496729500001 | 793156000000001600001
1                   | 0                             | 4294967295429496729500001 | 793156000000001600001
1                   | 0                             | 4294967295429496729500001 | 793156000000001600001
```

The Transaction Log backup jobs are running and backing up as expected, but the % of the log file used continues to grow due to normal traffic. How do I get SQL to reuse the transaction log file?

Comment: Check `sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states`, more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213319.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the CDC Capture job had stopped running. Restarting that (which took a while) then cleared out the log and allowed it to rewrite.